# Changing Erlang heart's timeout without restarting everything

Tags: erlang, heartbeat

I want to change the Heartbeat timeout of the erlang's heart without restarting everything. Is there a way to do that similar to how heart:set_cmd/1 let's me change the command heart runs in case of missed heartbeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but this thread gives a patch for OTP which allows it: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2011-April/057396.html